# UITableViewHeaderFooterView as UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a situation, where in one part, my Section header looks the same as a cell in another (the difference is the behavior i wanted to achieve, like section header floats on top).

So i would like to use my UITableViewHeaderFooterView class as a UITableViewCell

**Is this legit? Is there a better approach?**

```
MySectionHeaderView * headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"MySectionHeaderView"];

UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];


[cell.contentView addSubview:headerView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows in iOS must be displayed by a UITableViewCell or a subclass of it. So no, there is no better approach, because this is the only option.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: ok, and how about the reuse mechanism, how does this solution will behave?

Comment: Just fine. UITableViewCells give UITableViews a dependable way to identify the cell's contents without actually traversing the cell's contents. In reality you could abuse this system by generating random strings and setting that as your UITableViewCell's reuse identifier. The point to remember, however, is that UITableView doesn't really care what's in the cell, but only what UITableViewCell has to say about itself.

Comment: Upon re-reading your code, I just realized your getting your header view via dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier. This still will not break reuse (UITableView will just generate a new header view  the next time -dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier is called anyway), but for maximum code clarity it is better for you to merely alloc+init a new instance of MySectionHeaderView when configuring your new cell.

Comment: ok, so the header gets never reused and is always created as new?

Comment: Yes. In order for a cell to be reused UITableView must receive it from -tableView:headerViewForSection:. Since the headerView is not given back to the table view, the table view has no way to know whether the header view can be reused, and consequently will just generate a new header view each time -dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier is called. You can test this by calling -dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier multiple times yourself to see what I mean. (btw, if my answer has proven helpful please upvote and/or add a check. Thanks.)